# Phone Number on website showing up blue on an iPhone

Tags: html, css

I don't have an iPhone, but my client is telling me that the phone number (on the website I made for him) turns blue on his iPhone. What's the best way to remedy this?

*Note: It's not a link on my website, but the safari browser seems to make it into one*

```
<span>(873)984-0923</span>
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML/CSS?

Comment: It's just a plain phone number in a span.

Comment: Can you just add a class to that span and control the color with CSS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add this meta tag:

```
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
```

from the docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/_index.html

Comment: Will that stop the user from clicking the number and opening up the dialer? I want them to be able to click on it. It works perfect on my android phone (aka: It's clickable and brings up the dialer, but the text is white)

Comment: I know you can load iOS specific stylesheets (ex: <link media="only screen and (device-width: 480px)" href="iphone.css" type= "text/css" rel="stylesheet">) - perhaps you can override the link styling to change the color?

Comment: I was able to test this in the iPhone simulator in xcode on a VM. So, that line of code definitely changes the color back to white (from blue) and I've tested on Android if I still get an auto dialer and I do. So that'll have to do for now. Clicking in iOS doesn't bring up a dialer though.

Answer (score 2):

All phone numbers turn blue on iPhone so you can call them easily.  It's a built in feature of the phone

Comment: The background on the site is blue, so it kind of ruins the effect.

Comment: Understood- do what jacktheripper suggests

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but its the 1st result i got in google, and the accepted answer wasnt really good enough for me.

IOS actually makes the numbers into links, so what i ended up doing is wrapping phone numbers in a span:

```
<span class="iwrap">01234 567889</span>
```

Then adding a css style to target the IOS generated link tag:

```
.iwrap a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is the default iOS behaviour - to rectify try putting ASCII characters between the digits.

For example, the number `111 111 1111` would go to `111&nbsp;111&nbsp;1111&nbsp;`

or the number `111-111-111` would go to `111&ndash;111&ndash;1111&ndash;`

Alternatively use the meta tag in the `<head>` section of the document.

`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />`

Answer (score 0):

It's affected by the styling of your links. Just create a class for your phone numbers where you style your "a" tags the way you want them to be displayed. That way the user can still click through to make a call.